# Clicking all the buttons on the page with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to click all the buttons on a specific webpage. But the tricky thing is that the buttons only show up when a mouse hovers over them. After I finish clicking all the buttons on the page, I need to click the next page button. And again click all the buttons on the new webpage and so on.

I actually have a working script. But I am using setInterval function in javascript and I feel like it is a hacky way to do it. This is my working script:

```
alert ("Please refresh the page to stop");

setInterval(function () {

    var inputs=document.getElementsByClassName('tw-action-button btn btn-sm ng-isolate-scope btn-primary');
    var names=document.getElementsByClassName('screen-name');       

    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
        inputs[i].click();      
    }       

}, 250);

//Change the page in every 15 seconds   
setInterval(function () {

var nextButton=document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-default btn-forward');

    for(var i=0; i<nextButton.length; i++){
        nextButton[i].click();
    }

    window.scrollTo(0,0);

}, 10000);
```

However when I change the above code to the one below, the script doesn't click the buttons. Do I have to use the setInterval function? This is the modified but not working code:

```
function clickButtons(){

        var followButtons = $('.buttonClass');
        var numberOfButtons = followButtons.length;

        for(var i=0; i<numberOfButtons; i++){
            followButtons[i].click();
        }
        setTimeout(nextPage, 500);
    }

    function nextPage(){

        var nextPageBtn = $('.nextPageButtonClass');
        nextPageBtn.click();    

        setTimeout(clickButtons,500);
    }
```

This is the HTML for the webpage:
[image: HTML for the webpage]

Comment: What's different about the second listing? And what was the reason for introducing `setInterval()` in the first place?

Comment: Sorry about that. Somehow, I copied the same code. Now it is fixed. The setInterval was there to make it continuous. Because I couldn't find another way to keep clicking when I went to the next page

Comment: How is the script included in the page? Script on page A can't continue to run after page B loads and replaces page A. Or are your "pages" actually partial pages loaded via Ajax or something like that?

Comment: It is an extension, yes. The working extension (the version with the setInterval) works pretty well actually

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably consider using a bookmarklet or if the project warranted it, a browser extension.

Since your code needs to apply the same action to a number of pages, you somehow need to get access to the HTML of each of them, all the while retaining access to your JS code.

In the case of a bookmarklet, each time you click on it, you could process all buttons on the page, before clicking the button that advances to the next page. At this point, you'd just click the bookmarklet again.

In the case of an extension, I'd use a boolean value that indicated whether or not I wanted to perform the specified actions each time I visited a page from the owning domain. Then, once enabled, I'd just visit the first page and let it click all of the buttons, click the one that advances and allow the script to repeatedly be invoked.

I imagine that a bookmarklet would be the most suitable option of these two for this - quick, easy, few edge-cases to watch out for.

I have a bookmarklet that allows you to make *any* table on a page sortable. One simply navigates to the page, clicks the bookmarklet and then voila! Clicking on a column in the header row sorts the table based on that row. It's example code supplied by the sorttable js library (http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/#ajaxtables)

Here's the bookmarklet's 'URL':
`javascript:(function(){var s=document.createElement('script');s.src='http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js';s.onload=function(){sorttable.init();Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('table')).forEach(function(t){sorttable.makeSortable(t);})};document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);})()`

[image]

It seems to me as though it would be trivial to inset some code to perform the button-clicking into one of these.

Comment: It actually is an extension. I didn't add the background.js or any of those. What I don't understand is how come the setInterval version works but the other one doesn't work

Comment: If you include a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve you'd get a larger audience, since all (answerer's) effort could be put into solving the problem, rather than trying to mock-up an environment that seems to match your own. You've got the environment, the code and a debugger - this would be an ideal time to sharpen those skills and step through the code to work out why one approach fails and the other succeeds. Sorry, I've too many other things to do to be able to justify allocating enough time to be confident of correctly replicating and then solving the problem.:)

Answer (score 0):

That's strange, it should be working. I tried to produce the same logic as you did, and it worked successfully, here's my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <button type="button" onclick="doAction()" class="tw-action-button btn btn-sm ng-isolate-scope btn-primary"></button>
    <button type="button" onclick="doAction()" class="tw-action-button btn btn-sm ng-isolate-scope btn-primary"></button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function doAction(){
            alert("I'm clicked");
        }
        function clickButtons(){
            var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("tw-action-button btn btn-sm ng-isolate-scope btn-primary");
            for (var index=0;index < inputs.length; index++){
                inputs[index].click();
            }
        }
        setTimeout(clickButtons,500);
    </script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Then when I look again at your code, it looks like your JQuery was not loaded successfully, since you use selector, it's the only possibility I can think of.

```
var followButtons = $('.buttonClass');
```

To make sure it's loaded successfully, try to replace all of your javascript scripts, with this one, and see if it pops up an alert message :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("JQuery loaded");
    });
</script>
```